# How to change the color or background-color of the nav link using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone know, what's wrong with my code? It is when you are in the page the current color or background will be change. example the color is of the nav is red, so when you go to the about us the color of it will be yellow and the rest of the link still red,
 Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nhyr8pnd/

```
 <ul class="topnav" id="main-menu">
      <li ><a href="#" class="active" ><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home4</a></li>
  </ul>


#main-menu li {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

padding: 17px 25px;
}
#main-menu li a {
   color:#333333;
   font-size:15px;
}
#main-menu li.active a {
 color:#0198cf;
}
 #main-menu li:last-child  {
 padding-right: 0;
}
.active{background-color:#ccc;}



$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#main-menu li').click(function(e) {
    $('#main-menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Ps: I'm using header.php, so I don't need to copy all the nav in every page, so basically if the answer is putting an active class in every page is not an
 answer

Comment: If you add jquery in jsfiddle when you click it in the dropdown menu, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting li instead you should select a inside of li on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#main-menu li').click(function(e) {
      $('#main-menu li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).children("a").addClass('active');
    });
  });
```

Comment: still not working I already have the jquery min, but still when I click the other link it will be grey then when it goes to the page the grey still in the home, :(

Comment: it is working when it is < a href="#"> but when I put the the link, it is not working

Comment: which version of jquery you are using? I did test on your fiddle and worked there.

Comment: It will work when the page is blank/# but when you put a link to it ,it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check .It's work. You forget to put jQuery min file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#main-menu li a').click(function(e) {         
    $('#main-menu li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#main-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 17px 25px;
}
#main-menu li a {
  color:#333333;
  font-size:15px;
}
#main-menu li.active a {
  color:#0198cf;
}
#main-menu li:last-child  {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.active{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav" id="main-menu">
  <li ><a href="#" class="active" ><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-codepen" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" ><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: still not working I already have the jquery min, but still when I click the other link it will be grey then when it goes to the page the grey still in the home, :(

Comment: it is working when it is < a href="#"> but when I put the the link, it is not working

Comment: how? to stio the default behavior?

Comment: but it will prevent the link, the link is not working anymore when I putted that